# How to execute SQL Script with hdbcli in python

Tags: python, hana

I use the hdbcli in python to connect to a hana db.

SQL command execution works via cursor an my connection:

```
conn = dbapi.connect(
    address=os.environ['HOST'],
    port=dbconnectport,
    user=dbusername,
    password=dbpasswd,
    databasename=dbconnectdbname

)
```

...

```
   cursor=conn.cursor()
```

and execution looks like:

```
cursor.execute("Select USER_NAME from \"SYS\".\"USERS\" WHERE USER_NAME=\'%s\'" % varcrdbust)
```

For single queries it works fine. But how can I execute a sql script with a lot of spcial characters?
Via bash shell I can do this fo example in this way:
Create file on os level:

```
tee >> $PRIVFILE << EOF
WITH 
/* 

[NAME]

- HANA_Security_CopyPrivilegesAndRoles_CommandGenerator_2.00.000+

[DESCRIPTION]

- Generates SQL commands that can be used to grant roles and privileges assigned to one user to another user or role
SQL script text here.........
```

And then execute this via `hdbsql with argument -I <pathname/filename>`
Is there any alternativ in python? Maybe without usage of file creation on os level?

Thanks David

Answer (score 1):

All SAP HANA clients allow the execution of only a single command at a time.

The monitoring script that you chose as an example is in fact just one single command: a relatively large SELECT statement.

So, for every command, you want to have executed, you will need to send a separate `.execute`.

If you want to process a larger "script" file with several commands, you will need to look out for a "command separator" character (like `;` in HANA Studio or hdbsql) and build the individual commands from the strings between those separators.